# How to get kubernetes credentials for new Azure cluster?

Tags: windows, azure, kubectl

I deleted my old resource group with my k8s cluster, and made a new one and now kubectl can't get the new cluster's credentials.

When I run

```
>az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=myresourcegroup --name=mycluster   

    [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\azure\cli\main.py", line 37, in main
    cmd_result = APPLICATION.execute(args)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\azure\cli\core\application.py", line 157, in execute
    result = expanded_arg.func(params)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 358, in _execute_command
    raise ex
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 353, in _execute_command
    result = op(client, **kwargs) if client else op(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\azure\cli\command_modules\acs\custom.py", line 613, in k8s_get_credentials
    _k8s_get_credentials_internal(name, acs_info, path, ssh_key_file)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\azure\cli\command_modules\acs\custom.py", line 631, in _k8s_get_credentials_internal
    '.kube/config', path_candidate, key_filename=ssh_key_file)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\azure\cli\command_modules\acs\acs_client.py", line 39, in SecureCopy
    ssh.connect(host, username=user, pkey=pkey)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 305, in connect
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\paramiko\util.py", line 269, in retry_on_signal
    return function()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 305, in <lambda>
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Version

```
>kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"4", GitVersion:"v1.4.0", GitCommit:"a16c0a7f71a6f93c7e0f222d961f4675cd97a46b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-09-26T18:16:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.6.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup me.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com: getaddrinfow: No such host is known.
```

I tried deleting my existing kube config file but got the same error. How can I connect kubectl with my new cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I have got this error before, It seems does not install kubernetes CLI correctly.
Please try this command to install CLI:

```
az acs kubernetes install-cli --install-location=C:\some\directory\kubectl.exe
```